# How to return a pdf from an Azure App Service site with Python

Tags: python, flask, pdf, azure-web-app-service, fpdf

I am trying to return a PDF from an Azure App Service Python web site using `Flask` and `fpdf`. I used the Azure Flask example as a starter and it worked great. I then added `fpdf` in the `requirements.txt` and looked at the Azure log stream and I can see it being successfully installed.

I added the following code to my `app.py`.

```
import os

from flask import (Flask, redirect, render_template, request,
                   send_from_directory, url_for, make_response)
from fpdf import FPDF

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
   print('Request for index page received')
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
                               'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
   name = request.form.get('name')

   if name:
       print('Request for hello page received with name=%s' % name)
       return render_template('hello.html', name = name)
   else:
       print('Request for hello page received with no name or blank name -- redirecting')
       return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/jpg_to_pdf/<name>')
def jpg_to_pdf(name):
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.image(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/iamges/'+ name + '.jpg'), 50, 50)
    response = make_response(pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1'))
    response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=name + '.pdf')
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
    return response

@app.route('/pdf/')
def pdf():
    # save FPDF() class into a variable pdf
    pdf = FPDF()

    # Add a page
    pdf.add_page()

    # set style and size of font
    # that you want in the pdf
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 15)

    # create a cell
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = "GeeksforGeeks", ln = 1, align = 'C')

    # add another cell
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = "A Computer Science portal for geeks.", ln = 2, align = 'C')

    # save the pdf with name .pdf
    # pdf.output("GFG.pdf")
    response = make_response(pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1'))
    response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', 'GMT.pdf')
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
    return response
```

However when I try the `pdf` and `jpg_to_pdf/test' routes I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

I'm not sure how to enable HTTP logging or where I can see what the error is. Can anyone help to guide me in how to debug and fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure how to debug on Azure. Tried to switch on every log I could find, but it turns out I can run the app locally and find most of my errors.

Changed code to this and the pdf generation `/pdf` endpoint started to work:

```
@app.route('/pdf/')
def pdf():
    # save FPDF() class into a variable pdf
    pdf = FPDF()

    # Add a page
    pdf.add_page()

    # set style and size of font
    # that you want in the pdf
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 15)

    # create a cell
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = "GeeksforGeeks", ln = 1, align = 'C')

    # add another cell
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = "A Computer Science portal for geeks.", ln = 2, align = 'C')

    # save the pdf with name .pdf
    # pdf.output("GFG.pdf")
    response = make_response(pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1'))
    response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='GMT.pdf')
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
    return response
```